# I am working with java swing concept. combobox has value like "GST 18.00%" .I need only (18.00) as float. there any way to do this task

Tags: java, swing

I am working with java swing concept. combobox has value like "GST 18.00%" .I need only (18.00) as float. there any way to do this task...

Answer (score 0):

Do not add Strings to your ComboBox.  Instead, create a *value class* and add instances of that.

Swing calls the [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method of model objects in order to render them;  you can take advantage of that by overriding that method in your value class:

```
public class GSTValue {
    private final float rate;

    public GSTValue(float rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public float getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof GSTValue &&
            ((GSTValue) obj).rate == this.rate;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(rate);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("GST %.2f%%", rate);
    }
}
```

Then you can add the values directly to your JComboBox:

```
GSTValue rates = {
    new GSTValue(5),
    new GSTValue(12),
    new GSTValue(18),
    new GSTValue(28),
};
JComboBox<GSTValue> rateComboBox = new JComboBox<>(rates);
```

And you can easily retrieve that value at runtime:

```
GSTValue selection = (GSTValue) rateComboBox.getSelectedItem();
float rate = selection.getRate();
```